# Getting names/values of multiple properties

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Lets say I have one method, which extracts property name and value:

```
public TModel Get (Expression<Func<object>> param)
{
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var propertyName= ((MemberExpression)param.Body).Member.Name;

            var value = param.Compile()();

            // GetTableName() returns table name of TModel
            var query = $"SELECT * FROM {GetTableName()} WHERE {propertyName}='{value}'";

            var output = connection.Query<TModel>(query);
            connection.Dispose();
            return output.FirstOrDefault();

        }
}
```

and using it as:

```
var model = Get(() => foo.FirstProperty);
```

However, if I want to get name and value from the unknown number of properties, I do this:

```
public TModel Get(params Expression<Func<object>>[] param)
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var query = new StringBuilder();

            query.Append($"SELECT * FROM {GetTableName()} WHERE ");
            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)param[i].Body).Member.Name;

                var value = param[i].Compile()();

                query.Append($"{propertyName} = '{value}'");
                if (i + 1 < param.Length) query.Append(" AND ");
            }

            var output = connection.Query<TModel>(query.ToString());
            connection.Dispose();
            return output.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

But, implementation looks a bit 'ugly' and verbose:

```
var model = Get(() => foo.FirstProperty, () => foo.SecondProperty); // and so on
```

I could send manualy name of the property + value, however, I would like to keep the implementation as simple as possible and less verbose.

Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: Pseudocode, stub code, **hypothetical code**, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Also, what is even the point of this code? In what scenario do you know so little of your DB that you're trying to guess what fields a table has? Surely you're not building your own ORM? If so: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/07/24/dont-write-your-own-orm/ .

Comment: @BCdotWEB This is not hypothetical, obfuscated code and I'm not looking for best practices. Main point of this question is how to simplify method to get name/value pairs of multiple properties. And building a dynamic sql statement is not the same as creating own ORM. Reason behind: I'm using dapper.Contrib extention and Oracle database. However, these two are not very 'friendly', therefore, I have a method which writes sql statement based on the given object and then pass it to the dapper, which does all the ORM job.

Comment: how about passing `object[]` which would be something like `Get(() => new  {foo.FirstProperty, foo.SecondProperty})` then just loop over the object array.

Comment: aside from other comments, why do you  invoke " connection.Dispose()" if you're enclosing in "using"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate through all of the properties then reflection will help you to do that. You can find more at [MS docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.8)
Something like this:

```
public TModel Get<TParam>(TParam param)
{
        var allParams = typeof(TParam).GetProperties().Select(p => $"{p.Name} ='{p.GetValue(param)}'");
        var condition = string.Join(" AND ", allParams);

        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // GetTableName() returns table name of TModel
            var query = $"SELECT * FROM {GetTableName()} WHERE {condition}";

            var output = connection.Query<TModel>(query);
            return output.FirstOrDefault();
        }
}
```

But you have to think how to escape SQL injections. Because the value of `query` variable in current implementation could have potential vulnerabilities.